# Gradle 7.0.2 lintClassPath Could not parse module metadata

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I am trying to upgrade to Gradle 7 and running into issues when I am trying to run lintDebug. The app itself builds just fine. 
Here is the error 
Any suggestions? (I have ANDROID_HOME and local.properties setup correctly)

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not resolve org.testng:testng:7.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :core > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.2 > org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.7 > org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-testng:3.0.7
      > Could not resolve org.testng:testng:7.3.0.
         > Could not parse module metadata https://<ARTIFACTORY_REDACTED>/org/testng/testng/7.3.0/testng-7.3.0.module
            > Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Answer (score 1):

I totally forgot to post feedback.
Looks like artifactory was pulling in the wrong dependency and that is why I've gotten this error.